How to solve sqlalchemy Invalid-Request-Error?
I want to create a relationship between Users and Habits, but I have a problem:
 in get_property
    raise sa_exc.InvalidRequestError(
sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Mapper 'Mapper[Users(users)]' has no property 'users_habit'.  If this property was indicated from other mappers or configure events, ensure registry.configure() has been called.

code:
from ..models import Base
from sqlalchemy.orm import Mapped, mapped_column
from sqlalchemy import String


class Users(Base):
    
    __tablename__ = "users"
    
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    telegram_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(nullable=False)
    username: Mapped[String] = mapped_column(String(50), nullable=False)
    phone_number: Mapped[int]

...
from typing import List
from ..models import Base
from .users import Users
from sqlalchemy import ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.orm import Mapped, relationship, mapped_column


class Habits(Base):
    
    __tablename__ = "users_habits"
    
    user_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(ForeignKey("users.id"))
    user: Mapped["Users"] = relationship(back_populates="users_habit")
    habit: Mapped[List[str]] = relationship(back_populates="users_habit")

I tried to search for the problem on the Internet, but did not find.

The error message is informing you your Users class doesn't have a property named users_habit; inspecting your Users class, this is indeed the case - there is no property with that name.
To solve this, you need to update your Users class, adding the following:
users_habit: Mapped["Habits"] = relationship(back_populates="user")

While the above will address the specific error you encountered, there are a few other things you'll likely want to address:

phone_number: Mapped[int] is missing a column definition; depending on your specific implementation, simply appending = mapped_column() may be sufficient
In your Habits class, the last two lines are identical to the right of the = sign; I.e.: Habits.user and Habits.habit both refer to the same thing: relationship(back_populates="users_habit"). 
I doubt you actually want to assign that relationship to two separate properties of Habits, and regardless: only one of your PEP-484 typings can be correct (in this case, the first one: Mapped["Users"]). I'm unsure what you were trying to achieve with habit: Mapped[List[str]], but that's probably out-of-scope for this question thread.

